# How to get rid of progress-indicator?

Tags: intro.js

I am trying to launch a mini-popups via JS for a specific control. Ok, I admit that sort of defeats the purpose of [intro](http://introjs.com), but on that page there is really one control only that would "deserve" this treatment. So the navigation-controls, numbers and progess-indicator for a standard intro don't make sense there.

I followed the [doc](https://introjs.com/docs/intro/options/) and managed to eliminate numbers using 
     `showStepNumbers: false`,
however,

```
 showProgress: false,
```

as does not seem to work as documented. Am I missing anything or is it a bug?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/L1e6dso8/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you miss `showBullets` option!

There is a little way to play with some options:

```js
function showHelp()
{
var intro = introJs();
        intro.setOptions ( {
 showStepNumbers: document.getElementById('showStepNumbers').checked,
 showProgress: document.getElementById('showProgress').checked,
 showBullets: document.getElementById('showBullets').checked,
 steps: [
           {
 intro: "I really mean it!",
 element: document.querySelector ( '#bla' )
           }
           ]
        } );
        intro.start();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.7.0/introjs.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.7.0/intro.min.js"></script>
<div id="bla">
Hello World!
</div>
<button onclick="showHelp()">
Help!
</button>
<hr />
showStepNumbers:<input type="checkbox" id="showStepNumbers" /> &nbsp;
showProgress:<input type="checkbox" id="showProgress" /> &nbsp;
showBullets:<input type="checkbox" id="showBullets" />
```

Comment: Thank you - I missed that indeed!